# Write a program that outputs “I trusted you and you betrayed me” - but put it in lower camel case

Tags: c#, string, concatenation, comments

I need to write a program that outputs “I trusted you and you betrayed me” - but put it in lower camel case.

```
using System;

class IsThatAll
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string s1 = "Is ";
        string s2 = s1;
        s2 = s2 + "that ";
        //s2 = s2 + "all I ";
        string s3;
        s3 = "all ";
        s3 = s3 + "you";
        //s3 = s2;
        string s4 = "got?";
        s4 = "'ve ";
        s4 = s4 + "got?";
        Console.WriteLine(s2 + s3 + s4);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by lower camel case?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("i trusted you and you betrayed me");`

Comment: How is your example related to your question?!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly you want the output to be like this:

> iTrustedYouAndYouBetrayedMe

If so, you can do it like follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = "I trusted you and you betrayed me";
    var inputList = input.Split(' ').ToList();
    var output = new List<string>();
    var isFirstWord = true;
    foreach (var word in inputList)
    {
        var firstLetter = word.First();
        var restOfLetters = word.Skip(1);
        if (isFirstWord)
        {
            var newWord = $"{Char.ToLower(firstLetter)}{string.Concat(restOfLetters)}";
            output.Add(newWord);
            isFirstWord = false;
        }
        else
        {
            var newWord = $"{Char.ToUpper(firstLetter)}{string.Concat(restOfLetters)}";
            output.Add(newWord);
        }
    }
    string.Concat(output).Dump();
}
```

I did it in LINQPad.

Answer (score -2):

Convert the string to lower case or hard-code it in lower case. This method belowe converts to lowercase

```
String.ToLower()
```

So your code would be:

```
 String str = "I TRUSTED YOU, YOU BETRAYED ME" 
 str = str.TwoLower();
 Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: `ToLower` will just convert the full text to lowercase but he is asking to return to lower camel case